# how to search sum of numbers in Binary Tree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I need to search any combination of numbers in the BinaryTree that will give me the sum I am searching for.
For example, for the tree that have the numbers: 9,1,6,3,2,5 if the system will receive the sum of 18, it will return the string "9,1,3,5". How can I do that please.

The combination need to start from the root and down in Pathway & the method need to work in BackTracking recursion

the code that I wrote is:

```
public String path(int sum)
    {
        return path(sum, root);
    }
    private String path(int sum, Node t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return "";

        sum = sum - t.getNumber();

        if (sum == 0)
            return t.getNumber() + ", ";


        return path(sum, t.getLeftSon()) + path(sum, t.getRightSon()); 

    }
```

Comment: Should it give all combination? e.g. `6, 3, 2, 5` is also applicable here.

Comment: 9, 1, 6 is also a possible combination. Please elaborate on your exact requirement. Honestly, I wouldn't arrange your recursive call that way. This would only display the node that caused the sum to go to zero, because as you recurse out, the sum will actually be higher in each of the previous calls.

Comment: lets start from one combination for now ;) 
I forget to mention that the combination need to start from the root and down in Pathway.. & the method need to work in BackTracking recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive implementation is **really** close to what you need, but there are a few things that need some adjusting.
First, a recursive implementation requires two things to work:

1. **Base Case** that the problem can eventually reach by divide-and-conquer approach
2. **General Case** that is used to divide the problem into smaller pieces until reaching the *base case* desired.

---

You run into the problem that you are only printing the final node that makes your sum evaluate to zero, as you recurse out. This is because the last call will then recurse back to the method that called it, where the sum **is higher than zero**.

**if** that tree reaches a leaf and the sum was not found, then it doesn't exist in that sub-tree. 
`return "";`
**else if** the sum *is* found in the sub-tree. 
`return t.getNumber() + ", ";`
**else** we haven't reached the sum, and there are more children nodes. 
`path(t.getleftSon());
 path(t.getRightSon());
return t.getNumber() + ", "`

I haven't tested this exact code in an IDE, but the logic should be correct

Comment: hey, thanks for your help.
can you please wrote to me the code ? 
I am try to understand what you mean but not got well..
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: I won't give you the solution, but I will point you in the right direction! After all, the point of exercises like this is to develop your intuition for solving complex problems! "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day, TEACH a man how to fish an dyou feed him for a lifetime" -Confucius.

Comment: But, here is a page that has a similar problem set to what you have. I would highly encourage you to read through this. http://n00tc0d3r.blogspot.com/2013/01/tree-path-sum.html

Comment: appriciate that.
unfortunatly I dont understand how to fix my wrong.
I have tryed anything that in my mind..

Comment: @JavaBeginner Well, if you look at the link I posted, you'll notice that it has the answer basically spelled out for you lol.

Comment: the problem is that the method there is in boolean & I dont understand very good english.
there is any chance that you write to me the line codes of what I miss ?

Comment: Do you have to return a String in your method? I would suggest implementing it to return an int.

Comment: I have succssed ! 
thanks for your help @Evan Bechtol

Comment: Glad to help! Good job :)